# the byte string is same in python and c#,but md5 hashcode is different

Tags: c#, python, encoding, md5

I want to generate the hash code from a string,e.g."咖啡",but the hashcode I get from python and c# is different,the one from python is what I want

c#

```
String str = "咖啡";
MD5 m = MD5.Create();
byte[] data = m.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str));
StringBuilder sbuilder = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<data.Length;i++){
  sbuilder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
}
byte[] hex = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(str);
StringBuilder hex_builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(byte a in hex){
  hex_builder.Append("{0:x2}",a);
}
//md5 hash code
Response.Write(sbuilder.ToString());
//binary string
Response.Write(hex_builder.ToString());
```

python

```
#coding:utf8
str = '咖啡'
m = hashlib.md5()
m.update(str)
#md5 hashcode
print m.hexdigest()
#binary string
print ' '.join(["%02x"%ord(x) for x in str])
```

**binary string** is e5 92 96 e5 95 a1 both in c# and python

**md5 hash code**:

(c#)a761914f9760af3c112e24f08dea1b16

(python)3b7daa58a1fecdf5ba4d94d539fbb4d5

Comment: the c# passes a byte array to ComputeHash, whereas the python `update` takes string.  can you create a byte array in python and pass that to `update`?

Comment: FYI - i just ran your python code on my pc (python 2.5) and I get `a761914f9760af3c112e24f08dea1b16` as the hash - although I had to remove the #coding:utf8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string encoding might be different; therefore when you convert string to byte[] you probably get different values. Try printing those to see if they are the same.

Comment: I thought the default encoding in .net is utf16,and maybe I set python encoding to utf8(#coding:utf8 at top of the file),but the byte array is same: e5 92 96 e5 95 a1

Answer (score 4):

Had same problem. Was able to encode the text as "UTF-16LE" and the C# and Python both produced the same result.

```
def getMD5(text):
    encoding = text.encode("UTF-16LE")
    md5 = hashlib.md5()
    md5.update(encoding)
    return md5.hexdigest()
```

Comment: I need my C# code to return the value provided by the python code. Do you know of a way to alter the C# code to do this?